# AES Encryption in VB.NET similar to Java

Tags: java, vb.net, cryptography, aes

I'm currently trying to convert an existing code in Java into VB.NET that do an AES encryption of a string with a key in MD5 hash string.

Java code:

```
private static String a(byte[] paramArrayOfbyte) {
    StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
    for (int i = 0; i < paramArrayOfbyte.length; i++) {
      String str2 = Integer.toHexString(paramArrayOfbyte[i] & 0xFF);
      String str1 = str2;
      if (str2.length() == 1) {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        stringBuilder.append('0');
        stringBuilder.append(str2);
        str1 = stringBuilder.toString();
      } 
      stringBuffer.append(str1);
    } 
    return stringBuffer.toString();
}

public static String encrypt(String paramString) throws Exception {
    byte[] arrayOfByte1 = paramString.getBytes("UTF-8");
    SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5").digest("digiposoutletapp".getBytes("UTF-8")), "AES");
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
    cipher.init(1, secretKeySpec);
    byte[] arrayOfByte2 = new byte[cipher.getOutputSize(arrayOfByte1.length)];
    cipher.doFinal(arrayOfByte2, cipher.update(arrayOfByte1, 0, arrayOfByte1.length, arrayOfByte2, 0));
    return a(arrayOfByte2);
}
```

I've used the same type of AES with the Java which is `AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding`, but the result of VB encryption is always **different** with Java.

What's wrong here?

Comment: Why do you call `cipher.doFinal(..)` and `cipher.doUpdate(..)` in the same line? This does not make sense at all.

Comment: It produces same result if without `cipher.doUpdate(..)`

Comment: Try `AES.Key = temp`. `Dim hash(31)` and the both `Array.Copy` statements can be removed. MD5 provides a 16 bytes hash.

Comment: Also note the different encodings ASCII/UTF8 in both codes.

Comment: Wow it works, man! Thank you!

Comment: Beware that every time that some person calls out "it works" a cryptographer somewhere dies. Above code is nowhere secure.